# Finding longest length out of 3 different vectors in R

Tags: r, variable-length

I do not know if there is a function for this but I have 3 dataframes with different lengths. I was wondering if there is a way to find which one is the largest length and load that into a variable. For example:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(1:20)
z <- c(1:40)
```

I would want to use z as my variable because it has the longest length. Is there a function that can search through these 3 variables (x,y,z) and give me back the one with the longest length?

Thanks

Comment: Those are not `data.frames`, they are `vector`s

Comment: Thanks great insight

Comment: technically this should be the "the vector with the greatest length" or "the longest vector", not the "longest length", but this isn't englishgrammar.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: Thanks :) lol I appreciate you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can place it in a `list`, use `lengths` to create an index of maximum length and extract those element from the `list`

```
lst[which.max(lengths(lst))]
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Great thanks! I am also curious is there a way to apply the same idea for nrow() instead of length(). I tried that as well (just to try) and it did not work.

Comment: `lst[which.max(sapply(lst,nrow))]`

Answer (score 4):

if you have dataframe and not vectors:

```
lst[which.max(sapply(lst,nrow))]
```

data

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```